# Recode login page from JS and PHP to just JS... is it possible?

Tags: javascript, java, php, servlets

I just finished coding a simple login page with JS and PHP. However, my boss wants me to redo it without the PHP.

HOWEVER, he kept saying that to do that, I should be sending data to "http" (that's literally what he said) and I'm not quite sure what he means. He might have been talking about HttpServletRequests, but I am honestly not sure because there's a language barrier (his first language is Chinese).

To redo this code without PHP, are HttpServletRequests necessary or is there another, simpler way to do it?

login.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function() {

  var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
  var form_data = {
   username: $("#username").val(),
   password: $.md5($("#password").val()),
   is_ajax: 1
  };
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: action,
   data: form_data,
   success: function(response) {
    if(response.trim() == "success") {
     $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
      $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
     })
  }
    else {
     $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");
      }
   }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

doLogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="test";
$tbl_name="usertable";
$response="";

$connection = 
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("Unable to connect.");

$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count==1) {
  echo "success";
}
else {
  echo $count;
  echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Also, I understand that the code above may be faulty and filled with security risks and bad practises and I apologize for that.

Comment: Your wording is quite confusing. You said that you have to redo the project in "just Javascript", and then you start talking about Java and servlets. Could you edit your post to clarify your question?

Comment: @nkorth I edited the question and tried to make it a lot less wordy. Sorry about the confusion, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: It's much better now!

Comment: Do you want to execute a query on your database client-side ? That would really be a bad idea. There has to be some server-side coding, not necessarily in php though.

Comment: I still don't see what java and servlets have to do with this question.